# Signature of scalar products with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Consider the set  of scalar products:

$M(k) = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0&k^2 \\
    0 & 1 & k &0 \\
    0 & k & 1 &0 \\ k^2&0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}$ , $k \in \mathbb{R}$

- Determine the values of $k$ s.t. the scalar product is not degenerate, the values such that it has signature $(3,1)$, and the values such that it has signature $(2,2)$.

So, the values for which $M(k)$ is degenerate are $k=1$ and $k=-1$, struggling a bit with the determinant. How determine the signature with parameters? I tried with the characteristic polynomial - $((\lambda -1)^2 -k^2)((\lambda - 1)^2 - k^4)$ - but I don't think it's the right way (or the better one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $(3,1)$ must have negative determinant and "orthogonal" vectors of positive length.  $(2,2)$ must have positive determinant and vectors of both positive and negative lengths.  The determinant is $1-k^2-k^4+k^6=(1-k^2)(1-k^4)$, which is always nonnegative.  So signature $(3,1)$ is impossible.  Note also that this is an orthogonal direct sum of subspaces with forms $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & k  \\
   k & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & k^2  \\
   k^2 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}$.  Now a vector $(a,b)$ in the first subspace has negative length if $a^2+2k~ab+b^2<0$.  This is possible if and only if $|k|>1$.  Simiarly for the other subspace if $|k^2|>1$ which holds exactly when $|k|>1$.  Thus, you have signature $(2,2)$ when $|k|>1$, signature $(4,0)$ if $|k|<1$ and a degenerate form (of signature $(2,0)$) if $|k|=1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant